# Git add from 1and1 hosting returning permissions error

Tags: git, github, hosting

1and1 is NOT my favorite hosting site, but I'm required to use it for the time being.  I'm attempting to add all files from an existing repo to GitHub and it will not allow me to issue the command

```
git add .
```

When I do, the prompt returns:

```
error: open("logs/traffic.html/.md5sums"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file logs/traffic.html/.md5sums
fatal: adding files failed
```

I can manually add files with the git add FILENAME command, but I can not mass add there.  Am I missing something crucial to the process, or is there something else I am just not seeing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue on my own.  The .gitignore file was not set to ignore file 'logs/traffic/.md5sums' file, which I do not have access to open on the 1and1.com hosting site.  Adding the fire to .gitignore solved the issue.